# Why is 404 working when comment disabled

Tags: apache, http-status-code-404, httpd.conf

In my httpd.conf file, every mention of the ErrorDocument has a hash before it on the same line - meaning that it's commented out.

So why do I get a 404 error page on the browser? How does the browser know what message to display?

I must be getting a 404 because this is displayed in the error_log;

```
[Wed Jun 25 12:21:17 2014] [error] [client **********] File does not exist: /var/www/html/surveys/blahblah
```

Is there a default setting somewhere?

My environment is Linux, Apache and PHP

Answer (score 0):

You see `Apache httpd's simple hardcoded message`.

You need to configure an empty document as the `ErrorDocument` if you want a empty page to be displayed.

See the [Apache Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errordocument) or this [question](https://serverfault.com/a/389530/81247) for further informations.